# Visual Studio 2008 Designer File Bug?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, designer

This has been driving me crazy for months. I have a multiple projects that compile without errors. If I start copying and pasting controls (or even just plain 'p' tags) the designer will fail 1/2 the time with the error "the method or operation is not implemented". The complexity of the page doesn't matter. The 'solution' is to delete the designer file, exit visual studio, open visual studio and convert the offending aspx file to a 'web application' to regenerate the designer file.

This is a really annoying. I can't find any fixes on Google. Is there a way to disable the automatic designer file? Make it so it only generates on a 'build' command and not fail everytime I'm laying out a aspx page?

Thanks

Comment: My 'solution' was to install VS 2010. I never did fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To find the fix for the issue you would need to find the cause of the issue.  It might be possible to get more information on what is causing the issue if you attach a debugger to Visual Studio. This could be done by following these steps:

1. Open two instances of visual studio (run as administrator)
2. In one, open your project and get to a point right before the issue occurs
3. Attach the other instance of Visual Studio to the one with your project (Tools -> Attach to Process)
4. Perform the steps to reproduce the issue.

Note that to actually catch the exception you will need to change a few debugging options. First you would need to make sure that the Just My Code check box is unchecked in the General debugging options in Visual Studio. The second is on the exceptions dialog you will need to catch thrown exceptions. The exception dialog is under the Debug menu in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you, I've moved on to VS 2010, which never exhibited the problem.